# Store different collection in different files in MongoDB

Tags: file, mongodb, collections, store

I'm going to migrate a SQL Server database to MongoDB.
I have multiple tables with a lot of data.
I would like to know if is possible to break the single mongo db file into multiple files one for each collection in Mongo.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single mongodb data file. mongodb will allocate the initial file for the database and then add files as needed. On my Mac as currently configured it starts with a 64MB file, then the next is double that size (128MB) and doubles the next one etc till it get's to 2GB and then all files after that will be 2GB in size.

you can modify that with various configuration options http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/ but keep in mind storage file allocation is per database, not collection.

Comment: I have a bit more detail on file size options in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10001832/272109) StackOverflow answer.

Comment: When you start mongod from a shell you specify the --dbpath.
That is for the complete DB. So it is not possible to specify for a single collection?
Is there another way to partition the database like SQL Server?

Comment: Files are allocated per database, not per collection.